# How to get date difference if column is NA

Tags: r

I am trying to work out the difference between dates between two date columns in a dataframe df$started and df$done. The result is put in a third column called df$diff Some of the df$diff has NA and in these rows I want to enter the difference between the current date and df$started. How can I do this?

Comment: And you are expecting us to do all the hard work for you an create a reproducible example, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future, please follow the questions guidelines.

```
library(lubridate)
start = as.Date(c("14.01.2015", "26.03.2015"),format = "%d.%m.%Y")
end   = as.Date(c("18.01.2015", NA),format = "%d.%m.%Y")

diff = ifelse(!is.na(end),difftime(end,start,units="days"),difftime(Sys.time(),start,units="days"))
df = data.frame(start,end,diff)

View(df)


    start   end diff
1   2015-01-14  2015-01-18  4.0000
2   2015-03-26  NA  174.7846
```